# Issues Upgrading Tensorflow to 2.0

Tags: python, visual-studio, tensorflow

**Current Version of Python**

3.7.8

**IDE**

Error occurs when I run an .ipynb in VS Code

**Error**

> StdErr from ShellExec, Error processing line 3 of /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.52.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 168, in addpackage exec(line) File "", line 1, in  File "", line 580, in module_from_spec AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader' Remainder of file ignored Error processing line 3 of /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.52.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 168, in addpackage exec(line) File "", line 1, in  File "", line 580, in module_from_spec AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader' Remainder of file ignored Error processing line 3 of /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos...

**What I Have Tried**

I researched on google and came across this article: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5145. I followed the links and found the following change to be made.

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH": ""
}
```

The post didn't mention what file to make this change to so I changed the  settings.json file.  The syntax looked to have the same format.  Now my settings.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 3,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
        "psl.stepIn",
        "psl.stepOut",
        "psl.stepOver",
        "psl.sendToHostTerminal"
    ],
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH": ""
    },
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "author-header": {
        "author": "ANON",
        "contents": [
            "Email: ANON@gmail.com"
        ],
        "auto-comment-type": "#",
        "auto-space": false,
        "auto-title": true,
        "auto-date-type": 3
    },
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "python.pythonPath": "/miniconda3/bin/python",
    "jupyter.alwaysTrustNotebooks": true,
    "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [
    
    ]
    
}
```

The same error persists when I run the ipynb in VS Code.  The line is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```